# Binary search with returned index in STL?

Tags: c++, search, stl, binary, binary-search

I need a binary search function.

I couldn't find any function in the standard library that will return the index of the found item, and if it wasn't found, **will return the bitwise complement** of the index of the next element that is larger than the item I looked for.

What is the function I am looking for?

Edit:
I need to insert an item to a sorted vector and to keep it sorted. That's why I need to bitwise complement index.

Comment: I think `std::lower_bound` will give you the correct insertion point in order to keep your `std::vector` sorted. In fact I have written a `map` implementation using `std::vector` and `std::lower_bound`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I'll use it. sry :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm quite certain the standard library doesn't include anything to do *precisely* what you're asking for.

To get what you want, you'll probably want to start from `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound`, and convert the iterator it returns into an index, then complement the index if the value wasn't found.

- `lower_bound` will find the position of the first item with that value, or the position of the first item greater than the specified value, if the value you specified is not present (or `.end()` if no larger item is present).
- `upper_bound` will find the position just past the last item with the specified value (and, again, `.end()` if no larger value is present).

It sounds like you want your collection to contain only unique values (i.e., a value occurs at most once). If so, you probably want to use `std::lower_bound`. Then subtract the result from `yourVector.begin()` to get an index. Finally, compare what it points at to the specified value, and complement the index if they're not equal.

Comment: "upper_bound will find the position of the last item with that value (again, if any)" is not correct; instead, it returns the first element strictly greater than the provided value or the end iterator if not found.

Comment: @AshutoshAswal: Oops, quite right. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

There is no simple STL method which returns index against a sorted vector as far as I know, however you can use sample function below:

```
/**
 * @param v - sorted vector instance
 * @param data - value to search
 * @return 0-based index if data found, -1 otherwise
*/
int binary_search_find_index(std::vector<int> v, int data) {
    auto it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), data);
    if (it == v.end() || *it != data) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        std::size_t index = std::distance(v.begin(), it);
        return index;
    }   
}
```

Comment: It should be `std::size_t index = std::distance(v.begin(), it); if (it == v.end() || *it != data) index = ~index` (i.e. `index = ~index` instead of `index = -1`) per liran63's request about bitwise complement.

Answer (score 5):

This code should work fine

```cpp
auto itr = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), key) ;
index = distance(v.begin(), itr);
```

More about std::lower_bound() -
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdlower_bound-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

Using Jonathan's answer, a one line function, [for the case where we want to know at which index the value is or should have been if it does not exist](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-insert-position/):

```cpp
int searchInsert(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
    return lower_bound(nums.begin(), nums.end(), target) - nums.begin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, this "*will return the bitwise complement*" is a big deal for you and I do not understand what you mean.  That said, lookup [std::upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) and see if it does what you want.

Comment: I've edited my question to answer it. std::upper_bound won't help me with that.

Comment: Your 'edit' does not help in explaining the *bitwise complement*.  std::lower_bound should suffice for your purposes (did you take a look at the documentation?)

Comment: Probably liran63 wants bitwise complement, because they doesn't want to make additional checks whether the element exists or not (and thus should be inserted at specific location). It other words, liran63 wants the result to be `struct {std::size_t index; bool exists;}` logically and at the same time wants `bool exists` to be compressed into the highest bit of `std::size_t index` physically.

Answer (score 0):

using STL we can find the index

```
vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} ;
vector<int> :: iterator index;
index=lower_bound(vec.begin(),vec.end(),search_data);
return (index-vec.begin());
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as @Jonathan's answer, but lacks handling the "not found" case and is less readable. Also, `return` is not a function. So, no need to put the return value in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
int bin_search (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& val)
{
  ForwardIterator low;
  low = std::lower_bound(first,last,val);
  if(low!=last && !(val<*low)){
    return (low - first + 1);
  }else{
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Can you give us more information on how your code works, and why it will solve the question?

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
int a = 0, b = n-1;
while (a <= b) {
    int k = (a+b)/2;
    if (array[k] == x) 
    {
        // x found at index k
    }
    if (array[k] < x) a = k+1;
    else b = k-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a similar problem where I needed to insert an element in a vector while keeping it sorted. The solution I came up with is:

The function(modified binary search) returns the position where the value should be inserted.

```
int Position(vector<int> arr, size_t size, int val)//void for commented part
{
    int start=0, middle, end=size-1;
    while(arr[start] <= arr[end])
    {
        middle = (int)((start+end+1)/2);
        if (arr[middle] < val)
        {
            start = middle+1;
        }
        else if (arr[middle] > val)
        {
            end = middle-1;
        }
        else//arr[middle]=val;
        {
            return middle;
        }
    }
    mid = (int)((start+end+1)/2);
    //arr.insert(arr.begin()+mid, val); Can I do it here? got error trying to do it.
    return mid;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> x; cin>> val;
    mid = Position(x, x.size(), val);
    x.insert(x.begin()+mid, val);
}
```